# Installing webpack through npm causes 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error

Tags: webpack

I am receiving this error when trying to install webpack via npm with command:

```
npm i webpack --save-dev
```

I am on npm version 6.4.1, Node.js version 8.11.3.

I've pasted in a link to the debug log it produces. I think around line 90 is where it screws up, but I am unsure how to debug further from this point.

[Debug log](https://gist.github.com/rfrenchy/c8df3a791b392a71d88726f96301c243)

I'm able to install other packages fine, including webpack-cli.

How can I get it to install?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I've faced this problem recently, after rebooting os this issue gone.

Comment: I rebooted the os, but still have the same issue. ty for the suggestion regardless

Answer (score 0):

I have met the issue like you. Then I changed to use yarn to install ant it notice that

An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@xtuc%2flong: User not found".

So I go to file .npmrc to remove some redundant configuration (authentication) and I can install it successfully.

Comment: that fixed it, tyvm :)

Comment: How does one fix this without removing authentication (which is required in my case)?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try to remove you authentication firstly, after installing, add  the authentication and install the modules which need the permission to download.